# Does Chrome Devtools capture localhost network traffic?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, network-traffic

Network recording is on and I see the tool capturing how long it took the DOM content to load, but no breakdown on the network request. I ask because I am trying to learn about HTTP headers in the client/server model and having this visibility would be a big help.

I dont see any reference to it not being available on localhost in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network)

I attached an image to help with my description.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I only had network logging turned on for XHR requests. If you click the funnel it will show you what requests you are listening for. In my case I needed all requests enabled